# TradingView Charting Widget Timeframe Change

Tags: tradingview-api

TradingView provides its charting widget that can be used to insert stock charts in webpages. The code is available at the following link https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/ with the following code:

```
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span></a></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_029d2"
}
  );
  </script>
```

It looks like the 1-day candles setting default timeframe is 9 months.

Is there a way to set the default chart to have 1-year timeframe with the same 1-day candles?